# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "ausschalten" und "deaktivieren"?

Tags: difference, synonym

Der Originalsatz in einem Buch lautet "[...] und schalteten ihre Funkgeräte aus.".
Da ich den Inhalt des Satzes anders formulieren möchte, dachte ich daran, "deaktivieren" statt "ausschalten" zu schreiben.

Gibt es denn einen grundlegenden Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Wörtern? Bei Duden sind sie nicht als Synonyme füreinander angeführt, deswegen frage ich hier nach.

Comment: English has "shut off" and "deactivate" with similar meanings. I assume that the difference in usage between them is similar to the German analogs.

Comment: "außer Betrieb nehmen" wäre näher an "ausschalten" oder dem ähnlich gebräuchlichen "abschalten"

Comment: Warum genau möchtest du es umformulieren?

Comment: @Wolf weil ich diesen Satz in einer Arbeit zitiere und er sich nicht gleich formuliert sein darf.

Comment: @Wolf: "Außer Betrieb nehmen" verstehe ich eher als ein letztmaliges Ausschalten, wie in "Mina nahm heute Windows 7 außer Betrieb".

Comment: @userunknown Naja, ich kenne auch: "Aufzug vorübergehend außer Betrieb" - ich denke, es sind die größeren Nummern, die mehr erfordern als die Betätigung eines Schalters.

Comment: @Wolf: Deswegen ja "vorübergehend".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das sind auch keine Synonyme. Man schaltet ein Gerät aus, indem man den Ein/Aus-Schalter betätigt. Aber was genau »deaktivieren« bedeutet, ist unklar. Das kann von *stummschalten* bis *zerstören* reichen.

Wenn man mit einem Panzer über ein eingeschaltetes Funkgerät rollt, wird es danach nicht mehr aktiv sein weil es dabei zerstört wurde. Das Funkgerät wurde deaktiviert. Aber es wurde nicht ausgeschaltet.

Andererseits könnte man z.B. ein Mobiltelefon als *deaktiviert* bezeichnen, wenn man es lautlos schaltet. Dabei bleibt es aber eingeschaltet.

Comment: pikant, dass auch "ausschalten" als Synonym für "deaktivieren" in dem von dir beschriebenen Sinne (und Kontext: dem militärischen) gebräuchlich ist (allerdings völlig irrelevant angesichts der konkreten Frage)

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort!

Comment: @Wolf: Du hast mich missverstanden. Ich habe nicht behauptet, dass "deaktivieren" im militärischen Sinne gebräuchlich sei. Ich habe nur dieses Beispiel gewählt, weil nach diesem Vorgang das Funkgerät nicht mehr aktiv ist und somit deaktiviert wurde. Den Panzer habe ich gewählt, weil er schwer ist und harte Stahlketten hat und es bei einem PKW mit dem geringeren Gewicht und den weicheren Reifen sein könnte, dass das Funkgerät die Tortur heil übersteht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Entschuldige die Unterstellung, aber diese Bedeutung sprang mich plötzlich an. Vielleicht ist diese Wortwahl im militärischen (und anderen) Zusammenhängen sogar beabsichtigt. Man umgeht das ausdrückliche Erlauben jedweder Mittel, um das gegebene Ziel zu erreichen.

Comment: "Mit 4 Abwehrrecken konnte Maradonna als Spielgestalter ausgeschaltet werden." Maradonna hatte auch keinen Ein-/Ausschalter. Überhaupt hat vieles keinen Schalter, aber man kann es dennoch ausschalten, in dem man den Netzstecker zieht oder die Batterien entnimmt. Allerdings würde ich "ich habe meinen Account auf GL deaktiviert" meist nicht mit "ausgeschaltet" ersetzen.

Comment: Unter "ein Mobiltelefon deaktivieren" würde ich mir eher vorstellen, den Mobilfunkvertrag zu kündigen oder die SIM-Karte zu entnehmen, aber sicher nicht, es lautlos zu schalten.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn etwas einen Ein-/Ausschalter besitzt, würde ich bei *ausschalten*, *abschalten*, *ausknipsen* o. ä. bleiben. Für eine Zimmerlampe oder einen Rasierapparat wirkt *deaktivieren* komisch, dazu würde ich auch ein Funkgerät rechnen.

Deaktivieren kommt hauptsächlich in Frage, wenn

- es nicht mit einem Schalterumlegen getan ist, sondern ein komplexer Prozess nötig ist, beispielsweise bei einem Kraftwerk, einem Teilchenbeschleuniger oder etwas in dieser Kategorie
- bei Dingen, die sowieso nur sporadisch wirken, wie beispielsweise ABS, Airbag oder der Spurhalteassistent eines Autos, denen man nur die Möglichkeit nimmt, einzugreifen
- bei chemischen Vorgängen, bei den ein Stoff unwirksam gemacht wird
- bei im Verborgenen wirkenden Schaltungen, beispielsweise einer Alarmanlage, Bluetooth oder WLAN des Mobiltelefons geht m. E. beides.

Comment: Das dauerhafte Außerbetriebnehmen eines Kraftwerkes heißt nicht »Deaktivieren« sondern »Abschalten«. z.B. https://www.diepresse.com/5685140/deutschland-will-ab-2020-erste-kohlekraftwerke-abschalten oder https://www.greenpeace.de/themen/atomkraft/wie-wird-ein-atomkraftwerk-abgeschaltet

Comment: Das Unwirksammachen chemischer Stoffe würde ich nicht als »Deaktivieren« sondern als  »Inaktivieren« bezeichnen.

Answer (score 0):

Abschalten, the usual circumstance is to start logic circuit distances from .. to.
Signals are not logic. Artficial Intelligenc will never know other than the signals they are build with.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. If the question is in German, a german answer is much more useful.  And vice versa. Beisde that it looks more like a comment or a new question. The SE-model is different from most forums. Maybe take the tour? https://german.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The Tour, i'll take it.